# PHP variable not returning correctly on second page

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have an HTML page (has some PHP on it loading a functions.php and a header.php page) and upon post, it executes a function that is located on functions.php page successfully. I am trying to return a value back to the html page after post that would indicate a success or error but I need it to be displayed within a certain div, otherwise I would just let the functions.php page echo the result. I'd prefer not to use ajax but if I have to then I will.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to explain what is happening. Duh. So after post, it shows both the success and the error message, as if both if statements are being returned at the same time. It will show "Updated Successfully!" AND "Error!" at the same time.

Page 1 (html page):

```
include('session.php');
include('header.php'); // Includes Header Script
include('functions.php');

$cus_details=getAddress($login_id);

foreach($cus_details as $cus_details) {
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   $result = updateAddress($login_id, $_POST);
}
?>
<body style="background-image: url('Scripts/background.png'); -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">
<center><div id="signup">
<div class="container1">
<form class="addressForm" action="" method="post">
<?php if ( $result == true ) { ?>
    <br><br><center><span4>Updated Successfully!</span4></center>
<? } else if ( $result == false ) { ?>
    <br><br><center><span4>Error!</span4></center>
<?php } ?>
..... (more html)
```

Page 2 (functions page):

```
// Update Customer Address
function updateAddress($login_id, $data) {
    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    // Selecting Database
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection,"db_name");
    // SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
    $ses_sql=("update rma_customer_address set cus_address_1='".$data['address1']."' WHERE cus_id='$login_id' AND cus_address_type=0");
    if (mysqli_query($connection, $ses_sql)) {
        $success = true;
    } else {
        $success = false;
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
    return $success;
}
```

Comment: Why would you have to use AJAX? Do you understand the difference between it and what you're doing now? How is it failing? Does your server support short tags, because you're using them (<? instead of <?php) in the middle of your if/elseif which could be causing your issues...

Comment: What isn't working with your current code?

Comment: What happens if you just have `<?}else { ?>     <br><br><center><span4>Error!</span4></center>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: @William_Wilson welp, no it does not support short tags and yep, it was me using <? instead of <?php for the else if statement... Just got to work and still haven't had my second cup of coffee. My apologies and thank you.

Comment: You have a major sql vulnerability in your code by injecting data directly from $_POST into your SQL query.

Comment: @domdambrogia would you recommend something like ('". $data['address1'] ."') ?

Comment: I would recommend using a PDO and at the very least filtering your variables before inserting them into your database queries. 
PDO info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php `filter_var()` info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php . SQL injection info:  http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @domdambrogia any reason you suggest PDO over MySQLi? I have read that MySQLi is slightly faster for queries and I do have a database of over 20 million rows.

Comment: My comment was a little bit of a personal opinion, I feel that I see PDOs used in less spaghetti code bases, so my comment might have been premature. Both can definitely do the trick. Here is some more info for you: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: @domdambrogia Thank you very much for your useful information and links you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting @William_Wilson's comment as the answer as it was user error on my part which he saw.
Does your server support short tags, because you're using them `<? instead of <?php` in the middle of your if/elseif which could be causing your issues

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue here is you are closing out your PHP before actually running the else elseif code. Leaving you with standard HTML to output both your Success and Error message statements. I would try running those both in your PHP and using the echo command.

```
<?php if ( $result == true ) { 
       echo "<br><br><center><span4>Updated Successfully!</span4></center>";
      }
      else if ( $result == false ) {
        echo "<br><br><center><span4>Error!</span4></center>";
      }
?>
```

Given the foreach loop functions properly.

Comment: Thanks but you can do this both ways. Just because I end the code with <?php } else if ($var==false) { <? does not mean it is still not being used. I was able to get it to work using the method I had coded it, I just forgot to add the php part after <? when re-opening the if statement again.